# How can I test code that verifies data sanity?

Tags: testing, validation

I have a large data structure that gets read in from XML. I've been given a large list of constraints that should hold between data members. For example, one of the constraints might look like

```
some_complicated_function(data.childOne.fieldTwo.bar) < sqrt(
        data.childThree.fieldFive.foo.quux)
```

My best idea so far is to have tests that mock up the data in a way that fails exactly one of the constraints, and then inspect the logs. The problem with that is, everything is so inter-related that trying to arrange things so exactly one check fails -- or even tracking down all the checks that should fail from changing a 'clean' dataset in a certain way -- will take a good deal of mathematical trickery I'm not sure I'm up for.

I'm thinking that since I don't have any tools to see what the output of `some_complicated_function` *should* be, I'm stuck just looking closely at my code, and the pseudocode in the reference manual where the function is described, and making sure they do the same thing by hand. Similarly, I'll have to re-write the constraint logic in order to test it, so those tests wouldn't really help my confidence that my checks work as they should.

Comment: Not an answer, just general advice: first of all, starting to write tests for a big, untested system like this is a daunting task. What I found very useful in these situation is measuring coverage when running your test. It should tell you which cases you need to write tests for, allowing you to have an idea of how much work is left. And a particularly helpful thing it does is flagging up which branches you left out when testing a complex set of conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would test this is by splitting this up into smaller units that can be tested. You haven't given any indication of what language or environment you are working in so I'll assume it's an OO-type language... The general approach might hold true for any paradigm, but YMMV.

First of all: the *some_complicated_function* should be a method on a class. You test the implementation of the actual complicated function by passing it simple values that you control, and you validate the output. This isolates this part of the complexity by giving you one point to focus on when figuring out how the complicated function works. You test and develop it in isolation.

Secondly, the interaction between *some_complicated_function* and *sqrt* should also be part of a class. The fact that this relation needs to be checked means that there is some implied significance between the fields. Make a method on this class that, again, takes two values as a simple input. Mock out the calls to *some_complicated_function* by passing the class we made earlier to this class and calling onto that. Test this class by passing two values, asserting that the appropriate calls to Alpha are made and that the output is correct, depending on the result of Alpha. Remember that at this point you don't care how Alpha ACTUALLY works. All you are interested in is that the result of the call should be less than the result of the sqrt call.

Thirdly, have a class that you pass the XML to. This class simply calls the above class with the data that it fetches from the right fields. Testing this class simply means that you validate that a call was made to the validation method you created in step 2 and that the values from the correct fields are passed. In this test, you only care about the fact that the right fields are passed onto the method and that the validation logic behaves right depending on the result.

This might lead you down a path to having loads of small methods or classes, but in my experience this drives you to cleaner code that is easy to understand because it is highly focused (and SOLID).

Answer (score 0):

When you expect to test a specific constraint, you create unit tests. A unit test will have a small scope: usually one or several methods. In your case, unit tests may ensure that `some_complicated_function` returns expected values by calling it with different parameters. At this level, you don't have any XML or any “large structures”.

Once you have a series of unit tests which ensure that the constraints work in isolation, you may also be interested to know how those constraints perform when combined together.

To do that, you may use integration or system tests which, instead of focusing on a given method, will be at a much higher abstraction level. They will, for example, invoke your checker while specifying a sample XML file, and check whether the validation passes or fails. Here, you don't necessarily need to test every single constraint—this is the goal of unit tests. Instead, you get the overall picture.